# Can I easily find the God in kalyug

Tags: gods

I have heard couple of times older people talking and also in lots of spritual tv shows that it is easy to find God in kalyug as compared to any other yug(era).

Is it true? If yes, then why and how?

Comment: Definitely. Its easy to find God in all Yugas. Develop full devotion for God like Hanuman, no conditions, you are with God all time. In other Yugas, human life span was so long, hence long techniques were prescribed. This Yuga life span is short, so chanting his name with love will bring him next to you!

Comment: God is within you. Aham Brahmsmi

Answer (score 5):

In Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (12.3.52) we find the following verse:

> kṛte yad dhyāyato viṣṇuṁ
>   tretāyāṁ yajato makhaiḥ
>   dvāpare paricaryāyāṁ
>   kalau tad dhari-kīrtanāt
>
> Whatever result was obtained in Satya-yuga by meditating on Viṣṇu, in Tretā-yuga by performing sacrifices, and in Dvāpara-yuga by serving the Lord’s lotus feet can be obtained in Kali-yuga simply by chanting the names of the Lord.

In the purport of the above mentioned verse from A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupāda's Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam, we find information about Śrīla Jīva Gosvāmī quoting two verses pertaining to your question, the first from *Brahma-vaivarta Purāṇa*:

> ataḥ kalau tapo-yoga-
>   vidyā-yajñādikāḥ kriyāḥ
>   sāṅgā bhavanti na kṛtāḥ
>   kuśalair api dehibhiḥ
>
> Thus in the Age of Kali the practices of austerity, yoga meditation, Deity worship, sacrifice and so on, along with their various subsidiary functions, are not properly carried out, even by the most expert embodied souls.

... and another from Skanda Purāṇa:

> tathā caivottamaṁ loke
>   tapaḥ śrī-hari-kīrtanam
>   kalau yuge viśeṣeṇa
>   viṣṇu-prītyai samācaret
>
> In this way the most perfect penance to be executed in this world is the chanting of the name of Lord Śrī Hari. Especially in the Age of Kali, one can satisfy the Supreme Lord Viṣṇu by performing saṅkīrtana.

This is confirmed by Śrī Caitanya in *Śrī Caitanya-caritāmṛta Madhya 20.343*:

> āra tina-yuge dhyānādite yei phala haya
>   kali-yuge kṛṣṇa-nāme sei phala pāya
>
> In the other three yugas — Satya, Tretā and Dvāpara — people perform different types of spiritual activities. Whatever results they achieve in that way, they can achieve in Kali-yuga simply by chanting the Names of Kṛṣṇa.

The condition of society nowadays is spiritually degraded compared to previous ages, since most people live in the darkness of ignorance, chasing elusive material happiness, without being aware of their eternal relationship with God.
As the current circumstances are adverse for spiritual development, the process of realizing the Divine in this age is accordingly much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

This is primarily because in Kalyug very few people actually remember God or anything to do with positivity (Bhagvat Purana Mahatmya 1.31 to 36). So even a little good action can make you stand out and make you a candidate for divine blessing.

According to Bhagvata Purana (Mahatmya 2.4) Bhakti is the easiest and effective way to find.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! You are encoruaged to cite some sources.